# Change button value and color both

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to change value on click and color too. I am able to change value via js but unable to change color.
This is my Js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(el) {
        if (el.value === "P")
            el.value = "A";
        else
            el.value = "P";
    }
</script>
```

**And this is button:**

```
<td>
    <input id="press5" name="press5" type="button" value="<?php echo $ro5[$_SESSION['dyy']] ?>"
           onclick="return change(this);" onBlur="checkAvailability5()" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</td>
```

Please help me out. thanks.

Comment: Background color? Font Color?

Comment: background color

Comment: Side note, I'm sure you don't need `return` in the `onclick="return change(this);"`. `onclick="change(this);"` should suffice since `el.value` is assigning the value.

Answer (score 1):

This code will change your background color, font color & values of your input button. Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2samLzLg/16/).

```
<input type="button" value="P" onclick="return change(this);"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function change( el )
{
    if ( el.value === "P" ){
        el.value = "B";
        el.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
        el.style.color = "blue";
    }else{
        el.value = "P";
        el.style.backgroundColor = "lightpink";
        el.style.color = "red";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: yeah, it was easy.

Answer (score 0):

use the dom `style` object [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

```
function change( el )
    {
        if ( el.value === "P" ){
            el.value = "A";
            el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        } else {
            el.value = "P";
            el.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are missing braces in the `if` and `else`.